# Return message to bootstrap modal used for login

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website with the login in a bootstrap modal. If a user enters a wrong username or password, I want it to display a message on the modal. I've been able to pass the message as json via ajax, but IE tries do download the json as a file, and Chrome opens it in a browser window. How do I get it to stop doing this?

The login form is in a partial view that renders in the modal:

```
<!-- LOGIN  MODAL -->
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Log In to your Account</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">

    <p id="failedloginmessage" class="alert-danger"></p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="loginForm">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtUserName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", id = "txtPassword" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="btnlogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right link">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

My jquery triggered by the button click:

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Login/Login",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'application/json',
        contentType: 'text/html',
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success === "false")
                $("#failedloginmessage").html(result.response);
            }
        })       
});
```

My login controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(CModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Person user = new Person(model.UserName, model.Password);

        if (user.Login())
        {
            Session["user"] = user;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
        else
        {
            var result = new { success = "false", response = "User name or password is incorrect." };

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in returning a redirect response for an ajax call. Also your current code is not preventing the normal form submit (use `preventDefault()` or `return false` to prevent the normal form submit, in your click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is opening a new browser window because you are doing a normal form submit!

Why is it doing a normal form submit ? 
Because even though you have some code to wireup click event on the submit button to do an ajax post, you are not stopping the normal form submit behavior, hence it is making the normal form submit as well.

You can use the jquery `preventDefault()` method to prevent the normal form submit.

Also there is no point in returning a Redirect response from an action method which is being called from ajax call. You should return a JSON response back.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Login(CModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (yourIfConditionToCheckCredentialsGoesHereNow)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true ,url = Url.Action("Index","User") });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, response = "Password is incorrect." });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, response = "Error processing!" });
    }
}
```

And in the success/done handler of `$.ajax` call, check the response and do the next step as needed (show message/ redirect user to the `/users/index` page)

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnlogin").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (!result.success) {
                $("#failedloginmessage").html(result.response);    
            } else {
                alert('successful login');
                window.location.href = result.url;
            }
        }).fail(function(x, a, e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

});
```

You might also consider wiring up on the `submit` event of the form instead of the click event on the button.When user clicks enter button after entering the input form element values, it will submit the form.

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(result) {
        //existing code to check result
    }).fail(function(x, a, e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```